# Why does std::fstream use char*?

Tags: c++, vector, binaryfiles

I'm writing a small program that reads the bytes from a file in binary file in groups of 16 bytes (*please don't ask why*), modifies them, and then writes them to another file.

The `fstream::read` function reads into a `char *` buffer, which I was initially passing to a function that looks like this:

```
char* modify (char block[16], std::string key)
```

The modification was done on `block` which was then returned. On roaming the posts of SO, I realized that it might be a better idea to use `std::vector<char>`. My immediate next worry was how to convert a `char *` to a `std::vector<char>`. Once again, [SO gave me an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619806/cast-char-to-stdvector#answer-7619836).

But now what I'm wondering is: If its such a good idea to use `std::vector<char>` instead of `char*`, why do the `fstream` functions use `char*` at all?

Also, is it a good idea to convert the `char*` from `fstream` to `std::vector<char>` in the first place?

EDIT: I now realize that since `fstream::read` is used to write data into objects directly, `char *` is necessary. I must now modify my question. Firstly, why are there no overloaded functions for `fstream::read`? And secondly, in the program that I've written about, which is a better option?

Comment: Not really sure if this is helpful, but you can read it into the `std::vector` directly by using something like `.read(&vect[0], 16)` (or `.read(vect.data(), 16)` if you're using C++11), to avoid using the `char*` middleman. Just be sure you allocate enough space for the data using `.resize`.

Comment: I would say that not all buffers are `std::vector<char>` (sometimes you're a library given a `char*` to read data into). It would be a little weird if `std::fstream` forced you to use `std::vector<char>` instead of allowing many variants (raw arrays, `std::array`, etc.). Plus, sometimes you're reading/deserializing data straight into a type (like `int`), in which case a `std::vector<char>` is just... weird.

Comment: @Xymostech: Doesn't passing pointers mildly defeat the initial purpose of not using pointers? Or is passing a pointer to a `std::vector` safe?

Comment: @Cornstalks: Fair enough. But then couldn't there be an overriden constructor?

Comment: @VivekGhaisas: "is passing a pointer to a std::vector safe?" - as long as it's been pre-sized.  There's nothing wrong with using pointers for a binary operation - those read/write functions don't need to know about the objects being written, just an address and number of bytes.  If you want more safety in your own application, write a layer over them - e.g. a serialisation routine for your objects: then there's only one central place that needs to fiddle with address and `sizeof`.

Comment: "why are there no overriden constructors for fstream::read?" - `read` is a function not an object - it doesn't have/need a constructor.  There are no overloads because the two arguments it takes - the `char*` address and size in bytes, are both absolutely necessary, but nothing else is of any possible use.  Overloads are for when there are alternative ways of communicating the requirements, or some assumptions that may be useful defaults.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed the two up. I've changed the question to correct that.
Wouldn't a `std::vector<char>` type be a useful parameter too?

Comment: @Vivek: Not really, when you have iterator adapters such as `back_inserter`, and `std::copy`/`std::transform`.

Comment: @VivekGhaisas: for you, it appears useful.  For someone else, a `vector<double>` seems useful.  Someone else, a `deque<float>`.  Pretty soon there's so many overloads of `read()` it's hard to see what the `fstream` class does... ;-)

Comment: I need to find a broader perspective before I ask narrow minded questions. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

`fstream()` functions let you use `char*`s so you can point them at arbitrary pre-allocated buffers.  `std::vector<char>` can be sized to provide an appropriate buffer, but it will be on the heap and there's allocation costs involved with that.  Sometimes too you may want to read or write data to a specific location in memory - even in shared memory - rather than accepting whatever heap memory the `vector` happens to have allocated.  Further, you may want to use `fstream` without having included the `vector` header... it's nice to be able to avoid unnecessary includes as it reduces compilation time.

As your buffers are always 16 bytes in size, it's probably best to allocate them as `char [16]` data members in an appropriate owning object (if any exists), or on the stack (i.e. some function's local variable).

`vector<>` is more useful when the alternative is heap allocation - whether because the size is unknown at compile time, or is particularly large, or you want more flexible control of the memory lifetime.  It's also useful when you specifically want some of the other vector functionality, such as ability to change the number of elements afterwards, to sort the bytes etc. - it seems very unlikely you'll want to do any of that so a vector raises questions in the mind of the person reading your code about what you'll do for no good purpose.  Still, the choice of `char[16]` vs. `vector` appears (based on your stated requirements) more a matter of taste than objective benefit.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you're saying that `fstream` uses `char*` to allow finer control?
Also, you're suggesting that `char[16]` might be a better option in my case?

Comment: @VivekGhaisas No, it uses `char *` to be useful at all.

Comment: Arguably, it should be `void*` to be useful.

Comment: @VivekGhaisas: yes - with `char*` you can be pointed at anything anywhere in memory, whereas if it expected say a `std::vector<char>` or a `std::string`, then you have to live with the overheads in terms of additional data members in those objects (recording begin/end, capacity...), their choices as to where memory gets allocated, and their management of lifetimes.  Far less flexible.  `char[16]` sounds fine from the description in your question: it's the most direct representation of your data needs.

Comment: @TonyD: Thanks, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: @BenVoigt: agreed, though there's a certain (dangerous) convenience in being able to do arithmetic on `char*`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Actually, `void*` would be too dangerous because you could pass the address of any old thing. `char*` forces the caller to understand the thing they're pointing at needs to be able to be treated as an array of bytes (standard layout).

Comment: @GManNickG: Any old thing is what I want.  Maybe I want a buffer of `uint8_t`.  Or `int64_t`.  Or `double`.  The current interface is horrid for binary file I/O.  Which just reminds me not to use `fstream` for anything more than a simple log file.  (Better than `void*` would be a template `T*` with `enable_if` checking for triviality, but I don't know how to test a POD for the presences of pointer members)

Comment: @TonyD: If you want to do byte arithmetic, go ahead and use (unsigned) `char*`.  A `void*` argument will accept that just fine.

Answer (score 1):

To use it with a vector, do not pass a pointer to the vector.  Instead, pass a pointer to the vector content:

```
vector<char> v(size);
stream.read(&v[0], size);
```

Comment: And would you recommend I use a `std::vector<char>` at all, considering what the program does?

Comment: @Vivek: No, not unless you need a dynamic size, or swap.

Comment: I do need to swap the values of individual characters, but I don't need anything dynamic. So finally, `std::vector<char>` or `char*` ?

Comment: @Vivek: `char block[16]; stream.read(block, 16);` should work just fine if you don't need dynamic size